# Handling Long hyphen in Column Name R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have DF as Chk, and Column like Column1–Column1,  Which is not actually Hyphen and Might be long Hyphen as per my knowledge,  To Replace that Spl Character i tried using

```
colnames(Chk) <- sub("–", ".", colnames(Chk))
```

Which Dint work.Any other methods to handle this?

Just to show Difference i have posted the normal Hyphen Column1-Column1(Normal Hyphen),Column1–Column1(Not Normal Hyphen)

Comment: To replace the hyphen and en-/em-dashes, you could try using `sub("[-–—]", ".", colnames(Chk), perl=T)`. Adding `(*UCP)` or `(*UTF)` (or their combindation) at the pattern start in case it fails might be necessary. Note that `sub("[-—–]", ".", x)` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to just copy the character in the text and use it in `sub`

```
sub("–", ".", colnames(Chk), fixed = TRUE)
```

If that also doesn't work, then use punct

```
sub("[[:punct:]]", ".", colnames(Chk))
```

Comment: Yes i did the same Copied the character from that column name.but dint work, And i dont want to touch other column names having spl characters,Just the one with such Hyphen

Comment: I dont want to use "[[:punct:]] ", as i dont want to change other column names having Special Characters.

Comment: @Shivpe_R  In that case, use the `fixed = TRUE` argument in `sub`

Comment: This Works ,Thanks @akrun